# How do I use iwd in Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: networking, wireless, software-installation, network-manager, wpa-supplicant

I'd like to replace wpa_supplicant with iwd and use it for my wifi networking.  This is so that I can use and test Network Manager using iwd.  I can't seem to find instructions around relating to Ubuntu this anywhere.

If you read the [19.04 release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DiscoDingo/ReleaseNotes), it says:

> IWD can now be enabled for use with Network Manager. IWD is a new
>   alternative to wpa supplicant and is in testing for consideration in
>   the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the following works.

```sh
sudo apt install iwd
```

and create a new file called `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/iwd.conf` and add the following:

```
[device]
wifi.backend=iwd
```

Then disable wpa supplicant:

```sh
sudo systemctl mask wpa_supplicant
sudo reboot
```

Thanks to the ever-useful [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Using_iwd_as_the_Wi-Fi_backend).

**Update**:
[Ubuntu are now testing iwd](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/call-for-testing-improved-wifi-via-iwd/17795) for their 20.10 release.

Comment: Also had to do `dhclient wlan0` after connecting to a wireless access point. It would also be nice to show how to revert all tht.