# get file via sftp to local ip from ubuntu make local connection hang

Tags: files, sftp

been trying to figure out this for couple days..
the case was, if im trying to get file in ubuntu (with files or filezilla) from my local sftp server (android phone) the connection would drop after getting maybe 1-5mb. after that i cant event ping the ip from terminal..

in windows (with winscp), i can get file without this issue..

now im stuck without a lead, if anyone probably know this issue or any log i could get access to..

been using ubuntu for like a month now..

Answer (score 0):

somehow i manage to fix this by using iwd instead of the default wpa_supplicant.

the step in : https://askubuntu.com/a/1163689/1703959

another problem in my wireless card (mediatek mt7921e) internet speed drop when using bluetooth and wifi simultaneously is somehow fixed too..

what the heck is this iwd thing... lol

ubuntu is fun

Comment: "what the heck is this iwd thing", see: [man iwd](https://www.mankier.com/8/iwd). (or `man iwd`, on your local system )